# STM32F429ZI ADC converting too fast

Tags: adc, stm32

I am trying to trigger ADC1 to convert (for the moment) one channel of a STM32F429ZI microcontroller (on the Nucleo Board) by TIM2 every second.
With the code below I configured 180 MHz core frequency, a timer underflow every second (working), the ADC to convert channel 3 with 480 ADC clock cycles (@22.5 MHz) sample time and 12 bit resolution.
So with the abovementioned configuration I would have expected ~22 µs conversion time of the ADC.

To check for the conversion time I need to use Segger SystemView as I don't have an oscilloscope.
Contrary to my expectation the ADC interrupt service routine (ISR 34) is called 2.6 µs after the timer interrupt (ISR 44)

[image: (see screenshot)]

Can someone explain why the ADC is converting so fast?

Code:

```
/*********************************************************************
*                    SEGGER Microcontroller GmbH                     *
*                        The Embedded Experts                        *
**********************************************************************
*                                                                    *
*            (c) 2014 - 2020 SEGGER Microcontroller GmbH             *
*                                                                    *
*           www.segger.com     Support: support@segger.com           *
*                                                                    *
**********************************************************************
*                                                                    *
* All rights reserved.                                               *
*                                                                    *
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or         *
* without modification, are permitted provided that the following    *
* conditions are met:                                                *
*                                                                    *
* - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright   *
*   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.    *
*                                                                    *
* - Neither the name of SEGGER Microcontroller GmbH                  *
*   nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or      *
*   promote products derived from this software without specific     *
*   prior written permission.                                        *
*                                                                    *
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND             *
* CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES,        *
* INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF           *
* MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE           *
* DISCLAIMED.                                                        *
* IN NO EVENT SHALL SEGGER Microcontroller GmbH BE LIABLE FOR        *
* ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR           *
* CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT  *
* OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS;    *
* OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF      *
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT          *
* (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE  *
* USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH   *
* DAMAGE.                                                            *
*                                                                    *
**********************************************************************

-------------------------- END-OF-HEADER -----------------------------

File    : main.c
Purpose : Generic application start

*/

#include <stm32f4xx.h>
#include "SEGGER_SYSVIEW.h"

void ClockInit(void)
{
    uint32_t timeout = 1000000;
    
    // enable flash prefetch
    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN;
    // set 5 wait states (needed for high PLL frequency)
    FLASH->ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk;
    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_5WS;
    do
    {
        timeout--;
    } while (((FLASH->ACR & FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk) != FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_5WS) && (timeout > 0));
    
    // switch on external clock, bypass HSE with it and wait for clock to be ready
    RCC->CR |= (RCC_CR_HSEON | RCC_CR_HSEBYP);
    timeout = 1000000;
    do
    {
        timeout--;
    } while (((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY_Msk) != RCC_CR_HSERDY) && (timeout > 0));
    
    // configure (HSE as clock source, M = 4, N = 180, P = 2), enable and wait for PLL
    RCC->PLLCFGR = (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE | (4 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos) | (180 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos));
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    timeout = 1000000;
    do
    {
        timeout--;
    } while (((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY_Msk) != RCC_CR_PLLRDY) && (timeout > 0));
    
    // configure rest of clock tree
    RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Msk | RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_Msk | RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Msk);
    RCC->CFGR |= (RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV2 | RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV4 | RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1);
    
    // set PLL as clock source and wait until clock is ready
    RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_SW_Msk);
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    timeout = 1000000;
    do
    {
        timeout--;
    } while (((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_Msk) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL) && (timeout > 0));
    
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();
    
    // enable GPIOA, ADC1 and TIM2 clocks
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN;
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;
}

void TimerInit(void)
{
    // counter direction down, generate update event only on underflow
    TIM2->CR1 |= (TIM_CR1_DIR | TIM_CR1_URS);
    // set update event as trigger source
    TIM2->CR2 &= ~TIM_CR2_MMS_Msk;
    TIM2->CR2 |= TIM_CR2_MMS_1;
    // enable update interrupt
    TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;
    // set timer and reload value for update generation every 1000 ms
    TIM2->ARR = TIM2->CNT = 90000000;
}

void TimerStart(void)
{
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

void AdcInit(void)
{
    // PA3 as analog input
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE3;
    // set clock prescaler to 4 -> 22,5 MHz
    ADC123_COMMON->CCR |= ADC_CCR_ADCPRE_0;
    // enable timer 2 trigger event as start trigger on rising edge and generate EOC interrupt after each conversion
    ADC1->CR2 |= (ADC_CR2_EXTSEL_2 | ADC_CR2_EXTSEL_1 | ADC_CR2_EXTEN_0 | ADC_CR2_EOCS);
    // set 480 cycles sample time for channel 3
    ADC1->SMPR2 |= ADC_SMPR2_SMP3;
    // set channel 3 as first (any only) regular channel
    ADC1->SQR3 |= (ADC_SQR3_SQ1_2 | ADC_SQR3_SQ1_1);
    // enable EOC interrupt
    ADC1->CR1 |= ADC_CR1_EOCIE;
    // enable ADC
    ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON;
}

void InterruptInit(void)
{
    // Timer 2
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 3);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
    // ADC
    NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn, 2);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_RecordEnterISR();
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
    TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
}

void ADC_IRQHandler(void)
{
    uint16_t Value;
    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_RecordEnterISR();
    Value = ADC1->DR;
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
}

int main(void)
{
    ClockInit();
    
    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Conf();
    
    TimerInit();
    AdcInit();
    InterruptInit();
    
    TimerStart();
    while(1);
}

/*************************** End of file ****************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
I configured 480 clock cycles sampling time for channel 3 but then added channel 6 as the only channel to be converted - which had the standard sample time of 3 clock cycles. With channel 3 set as the input channel everything works as expected.